# Are card details autofilled in from Google Payments using account-stored cards or used with GPay button passed over to merchant?

Tags: online-payment, google-finance, google

Google Chrome offers autofill and sync for payment methods. It has the option to use cards that are stored/saved in your Google Account Payments Profile (instead of locally). Moreover, there is the option to use Windows Hello to confirm the cards (instead of CVV?).

When I confirm with PIN/fingerprint on Windows 10, does Chrome pass over my card's info to the merchant or the transaction happens/goes through Google? Since the card is saved in my Google account, how would it autofill with Windows Hello, since financial services providers are not allowed to store cards' CVV?

There are also some apps I used on android and some websites (Google Chrome on Windows 10) that offer GPay as a payment method (button to click on) instead of asking for card details. What happens in those cases? The payment is through Google or Chrome gives them my card info? From what I have noticed, there are no card info fields to fill in (which suggests the payment goes through Google), but what I find strange is that the transaction does not appear in the Activity of my Payments Profile.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's probably best to ask Google about this e.g. via the [Google Chrome Help Community](https://support.google.com/accounts/community).

Comment: What do you mean “goes through Google?”  They aren’t a bank, and the bank which issued your CC is the ones that approves and processes the transaction.

Comment: They aren't a bank, but they can process payments through their end. E.g. does the "GPay" button give my raw card info to the merchant or it gives an authorization/token to get the money?